# replace() not working when trying to remove HTML from string

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `fetch()` running which gets jobs. I'm pulling job descriptions which has HTML tags in them. For example:

**I have (snippet of code, full code below):**

```
var description = data.jobs[i].content;
var description = description.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '');
```

**This prints:**

```
<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...
```

It's like the replace function isn't even running?

**Code:**

```js
fetch('https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/cutover/jobs?content=true', {})

  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json(); // response type (json)
  })

  .then(function (data) {
    appendDataToHTML(data); // function that appends data to HTML
  })

  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });


  function appendDataToHTML(data) {
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById("jobListing");

    // get count of json objs
    var data_count = Object.keys(data.jobs).length;

    console.log(data_count);

    // for each object, create card
    for (var i = 0; i < data_count; i++) {

      var job_title     = data.jobs[i].title;
      var job_location  = data.jobs[i].location.name;
      var job_link      = data.jobs[i].absolute_url;
      var description   = data.jobs[i].content;

      var description = description.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '');
      var description = description.substring(0,200); 

      var html =
        '<div class="card">'+
          '<div class="card__body">'+
            '<div class="card__title">'+ job_title +'</div>'+
            '<div class="card__subtitle">'+ job_location +'</div>' +
            '<div class="card__copy">'+ description +'</div>'+
          '</div>'+
        '</div>';

      mainContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    }

  }
```

```html
<div id="jobListing"></div>
```

Comment: What is `data`? Hard to say without seeing the input. What's the expected output?

Comment: Don't use a naive regex to remove HTML tags. Use an HTML parser. That's what they're for. If you're doing this in the browser, it has one built in. :-) Note that replacing everything in `<>` will eat part of the content, for instance `<p>If a < b but b > c, then...</p>` is invalid-but-tolerated-per-spec (yes, [really](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#tag-open-state)) but will end up as `If a  c, then...`.

Comment: For instance, on a browser: `const div = document.createElement("div"); div.innerHTML = yourHtml; const text = div.textContent;`

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Have updated question showing full fetch(). Expected output is to return string with no HTML tags in them

Comment: You are creating three new ```description``` variables, when you only want one.  Not even sure how this is not throwing an error when you have three variables with the same name.

Comment: @Michael The magic of `var` and hoisting. If OP would have used `let` or `const` then this would throw an error.

Comment: @Andreas wouldn't that be bad coding practice though?

Comment: @Michael What exactly? Duplicate `var`s? Just go with `let` and `const`, there's no good reason to keep `var` alive.

Answer (score 1):

Like [@T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) commented: don't use regular expressions to strip html. Here is a way to let the browser do the work for you<sup>1</sup>. Note: code shortened a bit.

<sup>1</sup> actually, *your code does not return any html*. It is 'escaped', using `&lt;` and `&lt;`. You can also replace those entities with nothing.

```js
fetch('https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/cutover/jobs?content=true', {})
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json(); // response type (json)
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    appendDataToHTML(data); // function that appends data to HTML
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });


  function appendDataToHTML(data) {
    const mainContainer = document.getElementById("jobListing");

    // removes html from a string (using the DOM)
    const removeHTML = html => {
      const tmpDiv = document.createElement("div");
      tmpDiv.innerHTML = html;
      return tmpDiv.textContent;
    };
    
    // for each object, create card
    for (let i = 0; i <  Object.keys(data.jobs).length; i += 1) {
      const content = data.jobs[i].content
        .replace(/&gt;/g, ">")
        .replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
      const html = `
         <div class="card">
           <div class="card__body">
             <div class="card__title">${data.jobs[i].title}</div>
             <div class="card__subtitle">${data.jobs[i].location.name}</div>
             <div class="card__copy">${
                removeHTML(content).replace(/\n/g, "<br>").substr(0, 200) + `&hellip;`} 
              </div>
           </div>
         </div>`;

      mainContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="jobListing"></div>
```